# Are members of a diagonal positive definite matrix positive?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

If square matrix $M$ is diagonal and positive definite, does it mean that all $m_{ii}$ (diagonal entries) of this matrix are necessarily positive?

Comment: What is $x^tAx$ when x is any standard basis vector?

Comment: What do you mean by member of this matrix?

Comment: Remember that $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is positiv edefinite iff $x^{\mathrm T} A x > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n \backslash \{0\}$. So if $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is positive definite and a diagonal matrix, what can you say about $x^{\mathrm T} A x$? Especially consider $x = e_i$ for $e_i$ the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @John I mean all $m_{ii}$ where $M=[m_{ij}]$ and where $i \ne j$ then $m_{ij}=0$

Comment: I have edited your question. Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: @John Yes thanks

Comment: @gnometorule I dont find any ambiguity. What is wrong?

Comment: @Nofoos: I thought it was clear what you meant. If you follow the hint, you should see your result.

Comment: @gnometorule It seems the answer of this question is Yes. But in mathematics should be careful of solution bugs. That is why I ask to make sure.

Comment: The answer is 'yes'. :)